# access logs shiny server with ip address

Tags: r, server, shiny

I have hosted an app built using R and Shiny in the cloud.  The cloud infrastructure is as follows:

```
Centos 7.2.1511, R - 3.3.0, shiny-server - 1.4.4.802 and mysql.
```

The shiny-server is the `open source version`.

The shiny-server documentation page indicates that I can get the access logs (`not indicated as 'pro only'`) including the ip address of the users.  I have added the following access_log code in the shiny-server.conf file:

```
access_log /var/log/shiny-server/access.log default;
```

My current shiny-server.conf file looks like this:

```
#Instruct shiny server to run applications as the user 'shiny'
run_as shiny;
access_log /var/log/shiny-server/access.log default;

#Define a server that listens on port 3838

server{
  listen: 3838;

#Define a location at the base url

location / {

    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
    directory_index on;
  }

}
```

I stopped the shiny-server and started it again.  But still my logs are named as follows:

```
-rw-r----- 1 shiny shiny   725 Jul 26 09:37 testapp-shiny-20160726-093546-58006.log
```

Whereas I was expecting the logs with IP names.  When I open the log file, the following are the details I get:

```
su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:36182
```

How do I get the IP address of the users?  Or is it only for the Pro version..though the documentation clearly indicates the sections that are enabled for pro and i am sure the access logs were not specified.

Comment: I've just tried this and it's working on my installation. After adding the `access_log` line, restart the shiny server (`sudo service shiny-server restart` as I'm using Ubuntu), and visit the homepage, a new file `/var/log/shiny-server/access.log` was created with the right content (IP, time, request, etc). As mentioned in the doc, the access log is global with one log file for the entire shiny server (not per app)

Comment: @warmoverflow Many thanks....I figured that out lately...and also I had some error in my log rotate folder as well....now resolved.